# Codeigniter: Use of load_class

Tags: codeigniter, logging

I am writing my own logging class to save data in a DB. As I looked how CI is doing I noticed there is a `log_message()` function which handles the logging. There is a `load_class` function I can't assign to anything in the CI user guide.

**1** Why do they put this into an extra function?

**2** What/where loads this function files from?

Hope there are some CI guys how can answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**
You can write your own log class to override the default CI class:

```
<?php
// this file is /application/libraries/MY_Log.php
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {
    public function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE)
    {
        // Put your own logging function in here.
        // If you want it to still log to a file as usual, use this:
        parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);
    }
}
```

**Long answer:**

The `load_class()` function is basically a singleton loader.  If the class has already been loaded, return a previous instance; otherwise, load it and create the singleton.  It is very important in a framework like CI.  You have to know that every time you call, say, a database function, it is applying it to the same object, not instantiating a new one (that would get really messy).  All CI libraries function this way by default.

An important note: they changed how this functions significantly in version 2.0.  Previously, it would only load from the `/libraries` folder, but now, it will load from `/core` or wherever you specify when calling the function.

Here's the process for loading, say, the Log class (from your example):

```
$_log =& load_class('Log');
$_log->write_log($level, $message, $php_error);
```

This runs the following checks, in sequence:

1. If the Log class already exists, we're done.  Return the singleton.
2. If not, first check the `/system/libraries` folder for a "Log.php" file
3. If no file existed for step #2, now check `/application/libraries` for a "MY_Log.php" file (or whatever your subclass prefix is set to in your configuration)
4. If it loaded the default CI class (from the `/system` folder), but you DO have an extended class under `/application`, load that class too.
5. Return a new instance of the class (YOURS if it exists; otherwise, it's the CI_* class)

I've actually never needed to use the `load_class()` function, as it allows extension fairly seamlessly.  However, it's good to know how it works.

So, to override a class, first find where the original resides (usually `/system/libraries` or `/system/core`).  Put your extending file in the corresponding `/application` folder (this is important! If it's under `/system/core`, the extension MUST be under `/application/core`).  Prefix both the filename and the class name with `MY_` (or whatever you set in your configuration), and have it extend the `CI_` base class.

Comment: Thanks for the short answer. And many many thanks for the long answer! I think the CI people won't us to use it?! Why isn't it in the user guide?

Anyhow, now I know how to extend the log file. It is much better than building a new library file.