# PHP Class Extension Exceeds RAM  - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, overloading, extends

I am modifying the model class by completely replacing it. I also wanted to break most of the components in different classes and to be loaded when they are needed. This particular class has to be loaded in the constructor. A simple model of my classes is as follows:

**Model.php**

```
class CI_Model {
     function __construct(){
         load_class('Model_validations', 'core');
     }
 }
```

**Model_validations.php**

```
class CI_Model_validations extends CI_Model {
     private $validations = array();
     public function validates($field){
     }
 }
```

What I get from the following program is this:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in /xampp/htdocs/cms/system/core/Controller.php on line 233

Additionally I tried to remove `extends CI_Model` and it works just fine.
Also we can say that the `CI_Model_validations::validate()` method is called immediately after loading but it's empty and I don't see how that could cause the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It lookks like you have changed something, which caused CI to be thrown into a loop. I don't know the ins and outs of CI, but my guess would be that you omitted a required part of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because CI_Model tries to load CI_Model_validations which tries to load CI_Model again as it inherits from it. And CI_Model tries to load CI_Model_validations again and so on ...

UPDATE: My assumption above seems wrong from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774159/365188). It says that load_class is a singleton loader.

Comment: I believe that your explanation is correct. Exactly because it is a singleton loader. I actually need more than one instance of the class so It could work correct, which creates the paradox. Thank you.